# how to target the sibling of the element that has a same class as the element itself

Tags: jquery, this, selector, siblings

im trying to hide the sibling of an element but the sibling has the same class as the element itself

here is the jquery code and html code

```
<div class="a">this is the trigger</div>
<div class="a">this div is to be hidden</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".a").click(function(){
          $(this).html('this is triggered');
          $(this).siblings(".a").hide();
   });
});
```

i thought that the this woulg be able to do it for me

**Note:** for reasons these two divs(`.a`)**must** be of the same class

also note the divs are repeated

Comment: although you hard-coded it (with classname `.a`) but this should work.

Comment: Where is the issue? your code works perfectly.

Comment: @LGVentura the issue is that although it looks prefect it dosen't do any thing

Comment: it works perfectly. i made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7GbkN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is `next()`

```
$(this).html('this is triggered');
$(this).next().hide();
```

Comment: Must be some other issue. Check the console on Dev Tools.